Divi: The header background video flickers and is only visible when I scroll(mobile website)
I have the following problem: I have placed a header background video on my site, and everything works as I want it in desktop mode. However, when I visit my website on an iPhone using the Safari browser, I see only a black header instead of the video, and when I scroll slowly down the page, I see parts of the video. So it flickers, basically.
What am I doing wrong, and how can I ensure that my video is displayed correctly on mobile sites? Does anyone have a good tip for me?
Thank you very much for your help.
Link: https://elisanoelphotography.de/
Tried adding padding and tried with different browsers as well.
